# How do I take a screenshot of canvas in Phaser Framework?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, phaser-framework

I am making a game using Phaser Framework.  I try to use todateurl but it isn't defined, what am I doing wrong?

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1000, 700, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game');
game.state.add('boot', boots);
game.state.add('load', loads);  
game.state.start('boot');  
console.log(game);   // works
console.log(game.canvas);    // works
game.canvas.toDataURL();    //undefined
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok you need a link when user click on it it save the screenshot

```
var clickToSave= document.getElementById('linkeId');

function saveCanvas(link, filename) {
        link.href = game.canvas.toDataURL();
        link.download = filename;
};
clickToSave.onclick = function(){

var name = "name."+"png";

    saveCanvas(this, name);

};
```